# SortedList performance

Tags: c#, performance

I've found my app, which uses the `SortedList`, has a poor performance.
So I decided to try to improve the performance of my app.
I created the `FastSortedList` class which I think is faster than the original one.

```cs
public class FastSortedList<TKey, TValue>
{
    IComparer<TKey> _comparer;
    List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> _list = new List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>();
    Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _dict = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    public FastSortedList(IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        _comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<TKey>.Default;
    }

    public int Count => _list.Count;

    public IEnumerable<TValue> Values => _list.Select(i => i.Value);

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (_dict.ContainsKey(key))
            throw new ArgumentException("An entry with the same key already exists.");
        int index = BinarySearch(key);
        if (index < 0)
        {
            _list.Insert(~index, new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
        }
        else
        {
            _list.Insert(index, new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
        }
        _dict[key] = value;
    }

    public int IndexOfKey(TKey key)
    {
        if (_dict.ContainsKey(key))
            return BinarySearch(key);
        return -1;
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0)
            return;
        var item = _list[index];
        _list.RemoveAt(index);
        _dict.Remove(item.Key);
    }

    private int BinarySearch(TKey key)
    {
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = _list.Count - 1;
        while (lo <= hi)
        {
            int i = GetMedian(lo, hi);
            int c = _comparer.Compare(_list[i].Key, key);
            if (c == 0)
                return i;
            if (c < 0)
            {
                lo = i + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                hi = i - 1;
            }
        }
        return ~lo;
    }

    private int GetMedian(int lo, int hi)
    {
        return lo + ((hi - lo) >> 1);
    }
}
```

The used comparer:

```cs
public class TestComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return string.Compare(x, y);
    }
}
```

#### Comparing with `Stopwatch`:

```cs
private static void CompareWithStopwatch()
{
    int index;
    IEnumerable<int> values;

    FastSortedList<string, int> fast = new FastSortedList<string, int>(new TestComparer());

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        fast.Add($"test{i}", i);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"FastSortedList: Populate records: elapsed time: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} sec, total records: {fast.Count}");

    sw.Start();
    index = fast.IndexOfKey("test745723");
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"FastSortedList: IndexOfKey: key: 'test745723', index: {index}, elapsed time: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} sec");

    sw.Start();
    fast.RemoveAt(index);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"FastSortedList: RemoveAt: key: 'test745723', index: {index} elapsed time: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} sec");

    sw.Start();
    values = fast.Values;
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"FastSortedList: Get values, elapsed time: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} sec");


    SortedList<string, int> sorted = new SortedList<string, int>(new TestComparer());

    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        sorted.Add($"test{i}", i);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"SortedList: Populate records: elapsed time: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} sec, total records: {sorted.Count}");

    sw.Start();
    index = sorted.IndexOfKey("test745723");
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"SortedList: IndexOfKey: key: 'test745723', index: {index}, elapsed time: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} sec");

    sw.Start();
    sorted.RemoveAt(index);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"SortedList: RemoveAt: key: 'test745723', index: {index} elapsed time: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} sec");

    sw.Start();
    values = sorted.Values;
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"SortedList: Get values, elapsed time: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} sec");

    FastSortedList<string, int> fastRevrese = new FastSortedList<string, int>(new TestComparer());

    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 999999; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        fastRevrese.Add($"test{i}", i);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"FastSortedList: fastRevrese - Populate records: elapsed time: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} sec, total records: {fastRevrese.Count}");

    sw.Start();
    index = fastRevrese.IndexOfKey("test745723");
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"FastSortedList: fastRevrese - IndexOfKey: key: 'test745723', index: {index}, elapsed time: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} sec");

    sw.Start();
    fastRevrese.RemoveAt(index);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"FastSortedList: fastRevrese - RemoveAt: key: 'test745723', index: {index} elapsed time: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} sec");

    sw.Start();
    values = fastRevrese.Values;
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"SortedList: fastRevrese - Get values, elapsed time: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} sec");

    SortedList<string, int> sortedRevrese = new SortedList<string, int>(new TestComparer());

    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 999999; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        sortedRevrese.Add($"test{i}", i);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"SortedList: sortedRevrese Populate records: elapsed time: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} sec, total records: {sortedRevrese.Count}");

    sw.Start();
    index = sortedRevrese.IndexOfKey("test745723");
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"SortedList: sortedRevrese - IndexOfKey: key: 'test745723', index: {index}, elapsed time: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} sec");

    sw.Start();
    sortedRevrese.RemoveAt(index);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"SortedList: sortedRevrese - RemoveAt: key: 'test745723', index: {index} elapsed time: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} sec");

    sw.Start();
    values = sortedRevrese.Values;
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"SortedList: sortedRevrese - Get values, elapsed time: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} sec");
}
```

Results:
[image: withStopwatch]

#### Comparing with Benchmark.NET:

```cs
public class RaceBenchmark
{
    const int LENGTH = 100000;

    [Benchmark]
    public void InsertToSortedList()
    {
        SortedList<string, int> sorted = new SortedList<string, int>(new TestComparer());
        for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
        {
            sorted.Add($"test{i}", i);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void InsertToFastSortedList()
    {
        FastSortedList<string, int> fast = new FastSortedList<string, int>(new TestComparer());
        for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
        {
            fast.Add($"test{i}", i);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void SortedListIndexOfKey()
    {
        SortedList<string, int> sorted = new SortedList<string, int>(new TestComparer());
        for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
        {
            sorted.Add($"test{i}", i);
        }
        var sortedListIndex = sorted.IndexOfKey("test4321");
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void FastSortedListIndexOfKey()
    {
        FastSortedList<string, int> fast = new FastSortedList<string, int>(new TestComparer());
        for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
        {
            fast.Add($"test{i}", i);
        }
        var fastIndex = fast.IndexOfKey("test4321");
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void SortedListRemoveAt()
    {
        SortedList<string, int> sorted = new SortedList<string, int>(new TestComparer());
        for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
        {
            sorted.Add($"test{i}", i);
        }
        var sortedListIndex = sorted.IndexOfKey("test4321");
        sorted.RemoveAt(sortedListIndex);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void FastSortedListRemoveAt()
    {
        FastSortedList<string, int> fast = new FastSortedList<string, int>(new TestComparer());
        for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
        {
            fast.Add($"test{i}", i);
        }
        var fastIndex = fast.IndexOfKey("test4321");
        fast.RemoveAt(fastIndex);
    }


    [Benchmark]
    public void SortedListGetValues()
    {
        SortedList<string, int> sorted = new SortedList<string, int>(new TestComparer());
        for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
        {
            sorted.Add($"test{i}", i);
        }
        var values = sorted.Values;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void FastSortedLisGetValues()
    {
        FastSortedList<string, int> fast = new FastSortedList<string, int>(new TestComparer());
        for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
        {
            fast.Add($"test{i}", i);
        }
        var values = fast.Values;
    }
}
```

Results:
[image: withBenchmark.NET]

I will be glad for getting a code review for this implementation.

Comment: Unsorted data insertion into SortedList Is an O(n) operation as opposed to that of a similar class called SortedDictionary which has insertion of O(log(n)). Maybe you just want to use that one?

Comment: (@slepic: not far-fetched seeing `_dict = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>()` & `if (_dict.ContainsKey(key)) throw`.)

Comment: I see neither `implements IList<T>` nor `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>`.

Comment: Is this homework or are you trying to rediscover the wheel?

Comment: What is your point from doing that? by the way, mixing `List` and `Dictionary` is a bad practice. If you want a sorted `Dictionary` use `SortedDictionary` instead, which would save you the trouble !

Answer (score -1):

`GetMedian` -- (Please don't call it "median"; though it is the median of the indexes, it is not the median key.)

```
return lo + ((hi - lo) >> 1);
```

-->

```
return (hi + lo) >> 1;
```

Do you know if your compile will "inline" functions automatically?  If it does not, then do the inlining yourself:

```
int i = GetMedian(lo, hi);
```

-->

```
int i = (hi + lo) >> 1;
```

Consider frequency...

```
        if (c == 0) ...
        if (c < 0) ...
        else ...
```

If the number of items is low, it is good to test for 0 first; but I don't think that is the 'typical' case.  So, rearrange the 2 tests and the else.

Furthermore, the particular key "test745723" will go down exactly N levels each time.  When N is small, your code is "fast".  So, I dispute the results of the benchmark runs that involve just one key.

Comment: Your first suggestion is poor, because you've taken a well-behaved function and broken it when the sum is too large for the range of `int`.

Comment: @TobySpeight - OK, add an Assert at the beginning somewhere that aborts if the size of the list is more than half of MAX_INT (or whatever).  Executing that _once_ will be a lot more performant than repeatedly performing the extra subtract.

Comment: Abort?  Well, I suppose that's one possible choice...

Comment: If INT is 32 bits, fiddling with a list of more than 2^31 items will take a bit of time; that would move the user into a different level of "performance" issues.  Anyway, what happens if he goes over 2^32?  And then there is signed vs unsigned.  Etc.